# Nested objects and Aspose.Words LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

How I can use nested objects in Aspose.Words LINQ templates? F.e. I want to write something like that in a template

`<<[Person.Related.Car.Model]>>`

Is that achivable in Aspose.Words LINQ templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following article:
[Working with DataRow and DataRowView Objects](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Template+Syntax#TemplateSyntax-WorkingwithDataRowandDataRowViewObjects)

In order to make this work, you need to change your template like this:

```
<<[Person.Related.First().Car.First().Model]>>
```

Or like this:

```
<<foreach [in Person.Related]>><<foreach [in Car]>><<[Model]>><</foreach>><</foreach>>
```

Also, you can implement regular .NET classes - Person, Related, Car - and use XML deserialization. Then, it would be possible for you to use the wanted syntax, if an instance of the Person class is passed to the engine.